# Best way to ensure single instance but not global in C++

Tags: c++, design-patterns, embedded

I am developing a class to control a network adapter and I need to ensure that there's only a single instance of this class. Global access isn't necessary as this class is only used by clients that perform network operations, so I think that's not the case for the singleton pattern.

Currently I have a factory which has a static instance of this netAdapter but I'm not sure that's a good solution.

What's the best way to do this and avoid testability problems?

EDIT: I have more than one adapter(wifi, ethernet, 2G/3G/4G), but I can only have a single instance of each.

Comment: XY problem? Why do you care how many instances of class are there?

Comment: [Singletons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) are nice for this.

Comment: @Isuka, singletons are good for nothing.

Comment: @SergeyA Could you elaborate on that point? That could be interesting for the question too. Definitely not saying that a singleton is the best solution out there, but it does accomplish the work, no?

Comment: @Isuka, nothing to elaborate. There is no need to use singleton whatsoever. Never.

Comment: @Isuka [here, have a post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons)

Comment: Singleton is the common pattern where you need exactly one instance. Your "factory which has a static instance" is a singleton. That's called Meyers' singleton. Alternatively you can invert things and just pass an instance of the class in question, down as an argument. To everything.

Comment: @jaggedSpire Thanks for that, even though I was more asking for precisions so that the QA himself can see what are the pros/cons there.

Answer (score 3):

> I need to ensure that there's only a single instance of this class.
>
> ... so I think that's not the case for the singleton pattern.

Limiting a class to a single instance is the very definition of singleton pattern.

> What's the best way to do this and avoid testability problems?

I don't think testability problems can be avoided if you limit class to a single instance. Best approach might be to forget about such requirement.

> Global access isn't necessary

Then I suggest a local static variable:

```
void function_that_needs_a_single_instance_ever() {
    static singleton_class instance;
    // do something with your singleton
}
```

Comment: The static local suffers a number of problems, too. In Microsoft environments, they cannot be initialized safely in a threaded environment, even with C++11. We've got two bug reports open because of Microsoft games.

Comment: @jww thanks for the heads up. I wasn't aware of that particular lack of standards conformance.